# WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows not works for API>29 for dialog windows

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, windowinsets

```
class SuperDuperDialog: DialogFragment{

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(dialog!!.window!!, false)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { root, insets ->
            doSomethingWithDialogMargins()
            insets
        }

}
```

It's work great on devices with API <= 29, but on API>=30 setDecorFitsSystemWindows ignored.

Does anyone know why?